# Find new line in string (PHP)

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have address field which is simple text field.
user enters id using textarea.
My problem is i'm printing that address but php (Code-Igniter) takes it as a single line while user may have entered address in multi lines. How can I find that(new line).?

Comment: use `nl2br` function

Comment: maybe [nl2br() its in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: great, Its work. Thanks.